# Способ реализации прокрутки блоков

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Как реализовать прокрутку блоков в контейнере?

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #47ada5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-item"></div>
  <div class="container-item"></div>
  <div class="container-item"></div>
  <div class="container-item"></div>
  <div class="container-item"></div>
  <div class="container-item"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anonymweb/8Lqpywzh/)

Comment: помог ответ????

Comment: Т.е. в данном случае делается обертка для container  которая скрывает скролл?

Comment: именно - добавляется педдинг и скрол остается не видимым

Comment: Спасибо за полезный совет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте оверфлов на это: overflow-y: scroll;

```
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: А есть способ прокрутки без отображения скролла?

Comment: да можно -  создаете 2 дива, первый overflow:hidden; второй- overflow-y:scroll - один сидит в другом